# An Ancient Beauty

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My initials are "Y"
>
> My initial parts make a ditty sound
>
> My first's first is once round
>
> My second's middle is blue
>
> My whole is blue, too
>
> I'm in a pharaoh's gilded mask
>
> Putting me there was no easy task
>
> I ask you, who am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> Lapis lazuli

My initials are "Y"

> LL in Spanish is pronounced 'Y' (e.g. as in 'me llamo Stiv') - thanks to Stiv in the comments

My initial parts make a ditty sound

> "La" is a common refrain in a ditty, as in "tra la la"

My first's first is once round

> A "lap" is once around a track - thanks again to Stiv

My second's middle is blue

> "Azul" means blue

My whole is blue, too

> The lapis lazuli stone is a striking blue color

I'm in a pharaoh's gilded mask
Putting me there was no easy task

> It was used as eyebrows in the funeral mask of Tutankhamun (per Wikipedia)

I ask you, who am I?

Comment: Nice spot! The parts you're missing are rot13(YY va Fcnavfu vf cebabhaprq 'L' (r.t. nf va 'zr yynzb Fgvi') naq n ync vf bapr nebhaq n genpx) +1 :)

Comment: @Stiv - Good catches.  I'll edit them in.